# Codeigniter tidying up my controllers

Tags: codeigniter, controllers, performance

I've followed Codeigniter's configuration straight out of the manual - and just wondered if there was a simpler or more efficient way of coding my controllers...

eg.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->helper('segment1');
            $this->load->model('segment1/Leftsidebar_model');
            $data['articles'] = $this->Leftsidebar_model->articles();
            $this->load->model('segment1/Default_model');
            $data['head'] = $this->Default_model->segment1();
            $data['segment1'] = $this->Default_model->segment1();
            $data['segment2'] = $this->Default_model->segment2();
            $this->load->model('Rightsidebar_model');
            $data['coming_up'] = $this->Rightsidebar_model->coming_up();
            $data['featured_pages'] = $this->Rightsidebar_model->featured_pages();
            $data['recommended_link'] = $this->Rightsidebar_model->recommended_link();
            $data['testimonials'] = $this->Rightsidebar_model->testimonials();
            $this->load->view('head_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('segment1/__leftSidebar_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('segment1/__mainContent/default_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('segment1/__mainContent/segment2_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('__rightSidebar_view', $data);
            $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

helpers and models can be auto loaded, this can be specified in the confiq file. This will save you from having to manually load them.

As for the rest:

You can subclass CI_Controller. Eg:
My Controller extends CI controller and this would then contain a 2 methods

1) to load page head and header
2) to load page bottom

you could then subclass your controller from My_Controller and call those methods

```
load_page_top();
//insert whatever you have to load
load_page_bottom();
```

other than that the rest is up to you

Eg:

```
class Home extends MY_Controller
{
    index()
    {
        $data = get_data();
        load_page_top();
        //insert your views here specific to the controller
        load_page_bottom();
    }

    get_data()
    {
        //gather all your needed data here and return it as an array
        return data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I love this structure, clean and neat.

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // Load libraries, helpers, models
        $this->load->helper('segment1');
        $this->load->model('segment1/Leftsidebar_model');
        $this->load->model('segment1/Default_model');
        $this->load->model('Rightsidebar_model');

        // Data for views
        $data = array(
            'articles' => $this->Leftsidebar_model->articles(),
            'head' => $this->Default_model->segment1(),
            'segment1' => $this->Default_model->segment1(),
            'segment2' => $this->Default_model->segment2(),

            'coming_up' => $this->Rightsidebar_model->coming_up(),
            'featured_pages' => $this->Rightsidebar_model->featured_pages(),
            'recommended_link' => $this->Rightsidebar_model->recommended_link(),
            'testimonials' => $this->Rightsidebar_model->testimonials()
        );

        // Load views
        $this->load->view('head_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('header_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('segment1/__leftSidebar_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('segment1/__mainContent/default_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('segment1/__mainContent/segment2_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('__rightSidebar_view', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer_view', $data);
    }
}
```

Of course, the view loading could be managed in other way, having a view loading all common sections.

Answer (score 0):

I just write little additional library for rendering similar page blocks.
Something like this:

```
    class Display_Lib{
       private $_CI;
       private $_template_data;

       public function __construct()
       {
           $this->_CI =& get_instance();
       }

       public function set($key, $value)
       {
           $this->_template_data[$key] = $value;
       }

       public function get($key)
       {
           return $this->_template_data[$key];
       }

       public function get_template_data()
       {
           return $this->_template_data;
       }

       public function display_page($view, $data = array())
       {
           $this->set('content', $this->_CI->load->view($view, $data, TRUE));
           $this->_CI->load->view('templates/main_template', $this->get_template_data());
       }
}
```

Set this library in auto load:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database', 'display_lib');
```

And call it in controller:

```
class Main extends CI_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
        $some_data = array();
        $this->display_lib->display_page('views/main_view', $some_data);
    }
}
```